# Create button with onClick attribute and a parameter in quotes

Tags: javascript

When the below code creates a button, I want it to have the attribute addEvent('entered text here') but it is creating the attribute as addEvent(entered text here)

```js
let eventList = [];

function btnCreateEventClicked() {
    var event = document.getElementById("event").value;
    function createBtn(evt){
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
          btn.innerHTML = evt;
          btn.setAttribute('class', "evt-btn");
          
          btn.setAttribute('onClick', `addEvent(${evt})`);
    document.getElementById("event_btns").appendChild(btn);
    }
    createBtn(event);
    document.getElementById("event").value = '';
    
}


function addEvent(evt){
    eventList.push(evt);
    console.log(eventList);
}
```

```html
<div id="Input">    
<label>Create an Event: </label><input type="text" id="event">
<button type="button" id="add-event-btn" onclick="btnCreateEventClicked()">Create</button>
<div id="event_btns">

</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achive actually by doing this? I believe the solution is not passing a function name to the generated-DOM

Comment: Would you mind [marking the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as solution please ?

Answer (score 2):

add quotations between ${evt}

```
btn.setAttribute('onClick', `addEvent("${evt}"`));
```

Comment: Yep, this works (second " was off)   btn.setAttribute('onClick', `addEvent("${evt}")`);

Answer (score 2):

You need to an `onClick` function inside the create element. `setAttribute` will **not** work and will an error. Its good to have less code to achieve same results.

You can do all this in `one` function instead of creating `two` function.

Also instead of using `setAttribute` to set class just use `classList` and `add` to assign a class to your dynamically added element.

**Demo:**

```js
let eventList = [];

//Buttons
var eventBtn = document.getElementById("event_btns")

function btnCreateEventClicked() {
  var event = document.getElementById("event").value;
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = event;
  btn.classList.add("evt-btn"); //use classList.add()
  btn.onclick = function() { //function
    addEvent(event); //call function pass the evt
  };
  //Appned buttons 
  eventBtn.appendChild(btn);
  //Clear input
  document.getElementById("event").value = ''
}

function addEvent(evt) {
  eventList.push(evt);
  console.log(eventList);
}
```

```html
<div id="Input">
  <label>Create an Event: </label><input type="text" id="event">
  <button type="button" id="add-event-btn" onclick="btnCreateEventClicked()">Create</button>
  <div id="event_btns">
  </div>
</div>
```